# Angular: get input values in js function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My controller is too big so was decided to split it to several functions. So now functions don't see input values. Could you advice me how to solve this problem?

```
angular.module("sampleApp", [])
    .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {

        $scope.addNewUser = function (userDetails, isvalid) {
          doLogin();
        }

    });

var doLogin = function(userDetails, isvalid) {
            if (isvalid) {
                $scope.message = userDetails.name + " " + userDetails.email;
            }
            else {
                $scope.message = "Error";
                $scope.showError = true;
            }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rv6dqTECeD62HA1SgDM9?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

While you call function, you should pass parameters

```
$scope.addNewUser = function (userDetails, isvalid) {
    doLogin(userDetails, isvalid,$scope);
}

var doLogin = function(userDetails, isvalid, $scope) {
    //...
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/G66gFmJVhiXljyxgLDLP?p=preview

Edit: to get user name length update doLogin function:

```
    var doLogin = function(userDetails, isvalid, $scope) {
                if (userDetails)
                   console.log(userDetails.name.length)
                //..
    }
```

Comment: One more question: how can I get userDetails.name' length ?

Answer (score 2):

You have broken down the controller into several functions. However

```
var doLogin = function(userDetails, isvalid) {
            if (isvalid) {
                $scope.message = userDetails.name + " " + userDetails.email;
            }
            else {
                $scope.message = "Error";
                $scope.showError = true;
            }
}
```

is out of the $scope of the controller

> "defaultCtrl"

So if you want to have smaller controllers you can have several controllers and communicate them using an angular Factory.

To be honest. I think you should use the same controller to "CONTROL" all the stuff related with your login form.

Comment: One more question: how can I get userDetails.name' length ?

Comment: `userDetails.name.lenght`

Answer (score 0):

You have written your function outside the controller, therefore, the `$scope` is not available inside `doLogin` function. Apart from this, you did not pass values `userDetails` and `isvalid` values to `doLogin` call.

Replace your code with this:

```
angular.module("sampleApp", [])
    .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.addNewUser = function (userDetails, isvalid) {
          doLogin(userDetails, isvalid);
        }
        var doLogin = function(userDetails, isvalid) {
            if (isvalid) {
                $scope.message = userDetails.name + " " + userDetails.email;
            }
            else {
                $scope.message = "Error";
                $scope.showError = true;
            }
    } 
});
```